# Setting parameters just work through rqt_reconfigure, not rosparam

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rqt-reconfigure, rosparam, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS developers,

I am currently using [this](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan) depthimage_to_laserscan package. I wanted to change some parameters (for instance range_min). When I do it in rqt_reconfigure, everything is fine: the parameter changes, I can see it in rviz. But when I do it with rosparam set, rosparam get verifies that it is set, but neither the value changes in rviz nor in rqt_reconfigure.
So why can I change the parameter just through rqt_reconfigure and not the command-line tool rosparam?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with ROS kinetic.

I would appreciate every help, thanks in advance guys!

Best regards
cheesee61

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348015/setting-parameters-just-work-through-rqt_reconfigure,-not-rosparam/) by [cheesee61](https://answers.ros.org/users/51725/cheesee61/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When I do it in rqt_reconfigure, everything is fine: the parameter changes, I can see it in rviz. But when I do it with rosparam set, rosparam get verifies that it is set, but neither the value changes in rviz nor in rqt_reconfigure.

This is expected. See below.

> So why can I change the parameter just through rqt_reconfigure and not the command-line tool rosparam?

Because you should (and node authors should, and typically do) consider the `rosparam` uploaded parameters as akin to file-based configurations. With this I mean: those are typically read *once*, at startup of the program (nodes, in this case).

Just as with other programs, you could change values in the configuration file, but your *running* program would not notice anything has changed, as it's not paying attention to the configuration file any more after it has been started. ROS nodes are essentially just ordinary programs, so they don't notice these changes either.

But it would certainly be convenient if we could make running programs take a look at changed values in their configuration files. With Linux daemons (programs running in the background, somewhat similar to Windows services) and even regular programs, this is typically done by sending the program a `SIGHUP` signal ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP#Modern_usage), Windows and OSX have similar mechanisms). This tells the program to reload its configuration, as if it were shutdown and restarted.

For ROS nodes, we don't use `SIGHUP` (although we could), but there is a special interface called [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) which does the same thing (`rqt_reconfigure` is just a graphical user interface on-top of `dynamic_reconfigure`). In fact, it does a little more, as besides telling the node *something* has changed in its configuration, it also tells the node *what* has changed, and what the new values are.

Summarising: `rosparam set` changes the configuration of a node, but doesn't tell the node anything has changed. As nodes are not supposed to reload their configuration periodically (this is wasteful of resources), they don't realise something has changed and "nothing happens". With `dynamic_reconfigure` we do tell the node its configuration has changed, so it reads the updates and accordingly, you'll see the changes in behaviour (or visualisation).

And finally: the title of your question:

> Setting parameters just work through rqt_reconfigure, not rosparam

is not actually correct. Updating the parameters using `rosparam set` most likely works fine (you mention this yourself: you've used `rosparam get` to verify it). What doesn't happen is the nodes re-reading their parameters. But that is actually expected -- and recommended -- behaviour.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-31**:
Technically, nodes reloading their configuration periodically is called *polling*. For data which infrequently changes (such as configuration data), this is rather wasteful, as most of the times a node will be re-reading the exact same data.

Using `dynamic_reconfigure` makes everything *event-based*. This is efficient in this case, as the node will only act whenever there is something to actually act upon.

In a distributed system with potentially hundreds of nodes, only doing work when there is work is highly desirable.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-31**:
One could ask: but can't I just add `ros::param::get(..)` in my callback or `while`-loop? And the answer would be: certainly. However, as mentioned above, that would essentially be polling, which is rather wasteful.

Doubly so in this case, as `ros::param::get(..)` is somewhat similar to a service call, so you incur quite some overhead reading a single parameter (there is a *cached* version of `ros::param::get(..)`, which sort of combines notifications of parameter changes with polling, but it doesn't come with any of the niceties of `dynamic_reconfigure`, so I typically don't use it).

**Comment by [cheesee61](https://answers.ros.org/users/51725/cheesee61/) on 2020-03-31**:
Awesome explanations mate, thank you very much!

**Comment by [Enjoy_Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/56159/enjoy_robotics/) on 2020-06-27**:
Thanks so much for explaining the "rosparam set" and "dynamic_reconfigure", so easy to understand and useful.